# How to dynamically mutate "args" in Storybook v6 from the component's action?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, storybook

Let's see we have the simple component `ToggleButton`:

```js
const ButtonComponent = Vue.component('ButtonComponent', {
  props: {
    value: Boolean
  },

  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.$emit('toggle');
    }
  },

  template: `
    <button 
      :class="value ? 'on' : 'off'"
      @click="handleClick"
    >
      Toggle
    </button>`
});
```

And the story for that component:

```js
import ToggleButton from './ToggleButton.vue';

export default {
  title: 'ToggleButton',
  component: ToggleButton,

  argTypes: {
    onToggle: {
      action: 'toggle' // <-- instead of logging "toggle" I'd like to mutate `args.value` here
    }
  }
};

export const Default = (_args, { argTypes }) => ({
  components: { ToggleButton },
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),

  template: `
    <ToggleButton
      :value="value"
      :toggle="onToggle"
    />
  `
});

Default.args = {
  value: false
}
```

What I want to achieve is to handle `toggle` action inside the story and change `value` that I've used in `Default.args` object to change the button style by changing the class name from `.off` to `.on`.

Comment: did you get this figured out by any chance?

Comment: @SpaceOso unfortunately no. I have created a wrapper component just inside the story for a similar thing (control props inside the wrapper), but it's not exactly the same that I'm looking for.

Comment: @Ky6uk Could you share what that component wrapper ended up looking like? I am trying to figure this out myself

Comment: @MaximFedotov I just created a new Vue component inside `ButtonComponent.stories.ts`, let's say 

`const ControlComponent = Vue.component('ControlComponent', { components: { ButtonComponent } });` with dynamic properties inside that's being mutated by `ButtonComponent`. And then have used it instead of `ButtonComponent`.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same exact issue, and kept looking for days, till I stumbled upon this github post:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12006

Currently in my React (am sure vue approach will be similar), I do following:

```
import React from 'react';
import CheckboxGroupElement from '../CheckboxGroup';
import { STORYBOOK_CATEGORIES } from 'elements/storybook.categories';
import { useArgs } from '@storybook/preview-api';

export default {
  component: CheckboxGroupElement,
  title: 'Components/CheckboxGroup',
  argTypes: {
    onChange: {
      control: 'func',
      table: {
        category: STORYBOOK_CATEGORIES.EVENTS,
      },
    },
  },
  parameters: { actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on.*' } },
};

const Template = (args) => {
  const [_, updateArgs] = useArgs();

  const handle = (e, f) => {
// inside this function I am updating arguments, but you can call it anywhere according to your demand, the key solution here is using `useArgs()`
// As you see I am updating list of options with new state here
    console.log(e, f);
    updateArgs({ ...args, options: e });
  };
  return <CheckboxGroupElement {...args} onChange={handle} />;
};

export const CheckboxGroup = Template.bind({});
CheckboxGroup.storyName = 'CheckboxGroup';
CheckboxGroup.args = {
//Here you define default args for your story (initial ones)
  controller: { label: 'Group controller' },
  options: [
    { label: 'option 1', checked: true },
    { label: 'option 2', checked: false },
    { label: 'option 3', checked: false },
  ],
  mode: 'nested',
};
```

Comment: This is often the way it goes with Storybook, isn’t it? You’re looking for a feature that is never mentioned in the docs only to find it either deep in their source code or in a GitHub issue.

Comment: This works great, but the args state seems to be out of sync with controls state.

Comment: @T.Gaud what exactly your issue looks like?

Comment: @ProllyGeek if I change the state of my component with useArgs when an onClick is fired, the controls addon (which is included in storybook-essentials) doesn't reflect the updated state.

Comment: @T.Gaud are you talking about the actions panel in canvas tab?

Comment: @ProllyGeek well yeah, but the controls tab. e.g. https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-controls

Answer (score -1):

#### Cannot find module client-api?

If you're like me you have tried the suggestion in ProllyGeek answer's you probably got the following error:

[image: Cannot find module '@storybook/client-api' or its corresponding type declarations.]

In Storybook v7, useArgs should now be imported from **'@storybook/preview-api'**

Example using react, but it's pretty much the same in vue

```
import { Decorator, Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react'
import { useArgs } from '@storybook/preview-api'

import {
  Component,
  ComponentProps,
} from './Component'

const OnChangeSyncArgs: Decorator<ComponentProps> = (Story, context) => {
  const [, setArgs] = useArgs()

  return Story({
    ...context,
    args: {
      ...context.allArgs,
      onChange: (value) => setArgs({...context.args, value}),
    },
  })
}

export default {
  component: Component,
  decorators: [OnChangeSyncArgs],
} satisfies Meta<ComponentProps>


export const Overview: StoryObj<ComponentProps> = {
  //
}
```

---

My original answer stated that useArgs should be imported using '@storybook/addons' but cjl750 made me aware of my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up importing from @storybook/preview-api for use in a decorator with v7. Import from @storybook/addons is what you'd need if authoring your own add-on.